# How to track what documents are opened on a website

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I need to track who views documents on our website. I'd like to simply track the document, username, and date/time. I'd also like to keep the document links as "true" links so people could use shortcuts or right click and open in a new tab. I'm using ASP.NET 4.0 Webforms (VB) with a SQL Server backend.

One way would be to create an asp.net page that received the document path as a query string. Then on Page_Load handle the logging to the db and open the document. Is this the best way? What is the downside of this?  Is `Server.Transfer("documentlink")` the best way to open the document if I do it this way?

Am I correct in assuming there is no asp.net event that could capture when a document is opened?

Comment: You could just parse the access log, which'd record all the hits on those documents.

Comment: Will it be associated with a link? If so use a LinkButton and track the document click then redirect to the document (which if it isn't an image will open it as a download in the browser).

Comment: @MarcB What access log are you speaking of? IIS? How would I go about doing that?

Comment: @ThePower That was my first thought, but then that doesn't allow the user a shortcut path they could create to the document (a nice to have).

Answer (score 0):

What kind of documents to you have? If they are loaded through ASPX files you could use the EndRequest event in the Global.asax file:

```
Public Class Global_asax
   Inherits System.Web.HttpApplication

   Sub OnEndRequest() Handles Me.EndRequest
      Dim url As String = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath
      ' do some logging here
   End Sub

End Class
```

By default the IIS doesn't use the ASP.NET logic for none-code files. You could enable this in the application pool config and then all files will be served by ASP.NET enabling the EndRequest for all of them.